# Visual Studio 2017 Bug? C#

Tags: c#, hash

So I am coding this project that is an updater. So I generated a list of hashes into a text file of every file that the update will be applied to so a hashed entry in the text file looks like this:
FileName + " | " + MD5Hash
Now back into the C# project I add every hash and its filename to a Dictionary. After that i loop through every file in that fikder that the update will be applied to, find the value using the name, and compare the md5 hash of the one in the text file to the one I did in realtime. But the bug is that even though the two hashes being compared are the same it dosent do what I specify. Down below is the code (I will put comments on the lines where it dosent work properly):

```
//first check for hashes
            bool isTampered = false;
            string hashfile = "integrity.md5";
            string[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            //first build Dictionary for Hash
            string[] integrity = File.ReadAllLines(hashfile);
            Dictionary<string, string> hashes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach(string hash in integrity)
            {
                try
                {
                    int place = hash.IndexOf('|');
                    string filename = hash.Substring(0, place - 1);
                    string hashstr = hash.Substring(place + 1, hash.Length - (place + 1));
                    if (!hashes.ContainsKey(filename))
                    {
                        hashes.Add(filename, hashstr); //KEY:   Filename, Filename's Hash
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Error\n\n" + ex.ToString(), "There has Been An Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
                }
            }
            //-------------------------------<<
            richTextBox1.Text = "Integrity Check Results\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            foreach (string file in allfiles)
            {
                if (!hashes.ContainsKey(Path.GetFileName(file)))
                {
                    if (Path.GetFileName(file) != "OSH Updater.exe" || Path.GetFileName(file) != "integrity.md5") //DOSENT WORK WHEN IT SHOULD
                    {
                        richTextBox1.AppendText("\nMissing File: " + Path.GetFileName(file));
                        isTampered = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string cur_filehash = MD5Hash(file);
                    string keyhash = hashes[Path.GetFileName(file)].Substring(1);
                    //MessageBox.Show(cur_filehash + "\n!=\n" + keyhash);
                    if (cur_filehash == keyhash) //DOSENT WORK WHEN IT SHOULD
                    {
                        richTextBox1.AppendText("\nDifferent File Version: " + Path.GetFileName(file));
                        isTampered = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isTampered != true)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\nEverything Is Available");
            }
```

Comment: Is `==` the right way to compare `string` in C# ? Fwiw, this is not the case in Java

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet is correct.  You generally want to use `String.Compare`

Comment: yes it is or you can use string.Compare but i tried that already and it did not work

Comment: Are the hashes the same case?  Typically an MD5 is represented in binary, not a string, so case sensitivity doesn't matter, but if you convert to hexadecimal format, case would matter with that `==` operator.  You should try `string.Equals` with `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` if the values are the same but the case could be different.

Comment: I do not understand why you wrote `Substring(1)`, this will take the string from the second character (strings are 0 based), is that what you intended? BTW do you know that string have a method [String.split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx), you can use it like this: `hash.split(new Char[] {'|'})`.

Comment: There is no bug in the `==` operator for the `string` type. You have a bug somewhere in your code. But you didn't post a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, so it's not possible to say what that bug is. Also, if/when you fix your question, please explain what _"fikder"_ is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - "Fikder" is "folder" if you misplace your fingers on the keyboard :-)